# Simultaneously add key and + 1 value to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Can I simultaneously add a key to a dictionary and assign a key + 1 value to the key?

My original script in the interpreter looked something like this:

```
>>> if isinstance('my current string', basestring):
...     mydictionary[mynewkey] = mydictionary[mynewkey] + 1
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'mynewkey' is not defined
```

So I want to add mynewkey and a new value of 1 to mydictionary and ultimately be able to print mydictionary and come up with `{mynewkey: 1}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
mydictionary[mynewkey] = mydictionary.get(mynewkey, 0) + 1
```

Here `mydictionary.get(mynewkey, 0)` will return the value for the key named in `mynewkey`, or return `0` if no such key is present.

The easiest way is to use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), with `int` as the factory:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydictionary = defaultdict(int)
```

Any key you try to access that doesn't exist yet is then initialised to `0`, and you can simply do:

```
if isinstance('my current string', basestring):
    mydictionary[mynewkey] += 1
```

and it'll Just Work™

Answer (score 0):

At every occurrence of a newkey you need to initialize it first to some default value usually zero. After that you can increment it without any error message. Demo is shown below:

```
>>> a=['a','b','c','a','a','c']
>>> for mynewkey in a:
...     d.setdefault(mynewkey,0)
...     d[mynewkey]=d[mynewkey]+1
... 
>>> d
{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```